# Induction proof  concerning number of leaves in a heap

Tags: logic, induction

I have a question about one of my homework assignments. I have to prove the following:

> Prove by induction that a heap with $n$ vertices has exactly $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$  leaves.

This is how I am thinking right now:

*(Basis)* $n = 1$, $\lceil 1/2 \rceil = 1$ (trivial) 
*(Step)* $n > 1$, We assume that a heap with $n$ vertices has $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ leaves (IH).
 When have $n+1$ leaves we can distinguish two cases:

- *Either the new vertex is even:*
   When it is even, we have that $\lceil \frac{n+1}{2} \rceil$ = $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$.
- *Or it will be uneven*

I'm not even sure if this is the right way, or how to prove this correctly. I'm hoping for some hints/tips. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is the right way. Make a picture. Then you will notice that when you add an odd vertex then you just add a leaf to a vertex with one son (which is a leaf), what increases the number of leaves by one. If you add an even leaf to the heap, then you add this leaf to a vertex which was a leaf before this operation, so the total number of leaves is the same.

Additional hint: Is the number of vertices in a complete level in a heap even or odd?

Comment: I'm not sure what even and odd are supposed to mean in this context, could you elaborate?

Comment: There are $n$ vertices in heap $A$. We want to make a bigger heap $B$ by adding one vertex $v$ to the heap $A$. If $n+1$ is even, then I call this additional vertex $v$ "even" and if $n+1$ is odd, then $v$ is "odd".

Comment: Thank you, I believe I have the correct answer now.

Comment: @savick01: Makes sense, thank you and $+1$.